# How to write a file from Shared Library to workspace in JenkinsPipeline?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have pylintrc file in my shared library.
I am writing under stage : 
writeFile (file:".pylintrc", text:libraryResource("path/.pylintrc"))

Its failing my pipeline stage.
ERROR: No such library resource resources/.pylintrc could be found.

Comment: Did you load the library with `Library`? Going to be difficult to help without an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I was able to load the files. I created the folder structure as mentioned here : https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/06/27/speaker-blog-SAS-jenkins-world/